# Fazer um select com 3 tabelas e retornar na tabela 3 os registros do id da primeira

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho 3 tabelas, a primeira é ocorrencia, segunda é a individuos e terceira veículos. As tabelas individuos e veículos eu fiz subformularios de ocorrencias. Eu tenho a chave primeira na ocorrencia id_ocorrencia, as outras tabelas eu tenho a chave primaria delas e as chaves estrangeiras ligadas a ocorrencias. Eu quero na tabela veículos que tenha um campo que mostre os nomes dos individuos relacionados a ocorrencia, tem que ser os individuos que acabaram de ser cadastrados ou seja da mesma ocorrencia (id).

Comment: usa inner join para relacionar as duas tabelas pelo id (chave primaria da principal com a chave estrangeira da filha), selecionando os campos que desejar...

Comment: http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-inner-join-consultar-dados-em-duas-ou-mais-tabelas-29/

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o comentário:

```
SELECT i.nome, MAX(o.id_ocorrencia) FROM individuo i
LEFT JOIN ocorrencia as o ON i.id_ocorrencia_ind = o.id_ocorrencia
GROUP BY i.nome;
```

Comment: Fiz da forma que falou, mas está retornando todos os registros do campo que eu quero da tabela 2, o que eu queria por exemplo, a pessoa digita a tabela 1(principal) e depois a tabela 2 (filho) no filho tem um campo nome, que eu queria que apareçam em um campo na tabela 3 um ou todos os nomes digitais na tabela 2 relacionados ao ultimo id. Talvez seria alguma relação com ultimo id. obrigado Luiz

Comment: Não entendi, me passa o modelo E tbm não entendi o q vc quer, use o sqlfiddle.com e me passa o link que tento te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz vou colocar no sqlfiddle.com, mas só para ser mais claro, tenho 3 tabelas, a primeira é ocorrencia, segunda é a individuos e terceira veículos. As tabelas individuos e veículos eu fiz subformularios de ocorrencias. Eu tenho a chave primeira na ocorrencia id_ocorrencia, as outras tabelas eu tenho a chave primaria delas e as chaves estrangeiras ligadas a ocorrencias. Eu quero na tabela veículos que tenha um campo que mostre os nomes dos individuos relacionados a ocorrencia, tem que ser os individuos que acabaram de ser cadastrados ou seja da mesma ocorrencia (id).

Comment: Luiz Sérgio segue o link do esquema do modelo do banco que fiz, desde já agradeço imensamente. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TaSb7IsnNEUfY-Ht22KQ_Hoz9AyklW3Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Edita a pergunta com a descrição duas msgs acima e a imagem logo acima, que eu respondo

Comment: Para melhor entendimento

Comment: Deu esse erro:Erro na consulta (1054): Unknown column 'o.id_ocorrencia' in 'having clause'

Comment: Tirei o havinbg da consulta. Tenta denovo.

Comment: Não deu erro, porém mostra os ids da ocorrências com seus respectivos nomes, e não somente o id atual (ultimo id da ocorrência do banco com seu respectivo nome). Obrigado Luiz

Comment: tentei dessa forma:                                                                            select max(id_ocorrencia_ind), nome
from individuos
order by nome                                                                                       . O id parece o último porém o nome não.